# What does this typedef mean?

Tags: c, typedef

I am new to C, and this typedef looks a little bit strange to me. Can someone explain what it does?

```
typedef void (*alpm_cb_log)(alpm_loglevel_t, const char *, va_list);
```

It is in a header file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Simple example.
Declaration:

```
typedef int myint.
```

Use:

```
myint number = 7;
```

**myint is a synonym of int**.

your example

```
typedef void (*alpm_cb_log)(alpm_loglevel_t, const char *, va_list);
```

this is a pointer to a function

```
(*alpm_cb_log)
```

The arguments are

```
(alpm_loglevel_t, const char *, va_list)
```

and does not return anything.

```
void
```

The general rule with the use of typedef is to write out a declaration as if
you were declaring variables of the types that you want

Answer (score 7):

You can use cdecl.org : [http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=void+%28*alpm_cb_log%29%28alpm_loglevel_t%2C+const+char+*%2C+va_list%29+](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=void%20%28%2aalpm_cb_log%29%28alpm_loglevel_t,%20const%20char%20%2a,%20va_list%29%20)

It says:

declare alpm_cb_log as pointer to function (alpm_loglevel_t, pointer to const char, va_list) returning void

in this case, it is a typedef, not a declaration.

Answer (score 4):

It defines `alpm_cb_log` to be a type for a pointer to a function that takes the arguments `alpm_loglevel_t, const char *, va_list` and returns `void`.

Answer (score 3):

These do look weird if you've never seen them before. It's a typedef `alpm_cb_log` for a pointer to a function returning void, taking two or more arguments: an `alpm_loglevel_t`, a `const char *`, and a variable argument list.

Answer (score 2):

it creates the alais alpm_cb_log which is a pointer to a function that returns void and takes three paramaters. 1. a alpm_loglevel_t 2. const char *. 3 a varaibale argument list.