# How is this typedef possible?

Tags: c, typedef

In [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36971158/4354477) I've encountered a *very* weird `typedef`:

```
struct Date {
    int day, month, year;
} typedef date_s;
```

I've always been seeing `typedef`s following this 'rule':

```
typedef <existing> <new>;
```

For example:

```
typedef unsigned long long ull;
typedef int kph; // speed
typedef void (*alpm_cb_log)(alpm_loglevel_t, const char *, va_list);

typedef int int_t;
typedef char char_t, *char_p, (*fp)(void);
```

<sub>The 4th one is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9322788/4354477), the 5th and 6th are from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/typedef)</sub>

---

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/252780/4354477) is how I would `typedef` a `struct`:

```
typedef struct {
    int a, b, c;
} data;

// and then use it
data Something;
```

---

The question is *how is this even possible to write such a `typedef`*? It doesn't even make sense (at least to me).

`clang` doesn't give any errors or warnings, even with `-Wall -Wextra`.

**Bonus question:** should I advise the author of the question where this code could be found *to avoid using* such a `typedef` (because it's very unusual and may lead to confusion)?

Comment: It is fine, though unusual. Much as int const i;

Comment: @piling I like `int const i` much more than `const int i`. It's less confusing when working with pointers, since you only have to follow one general rule: "Whatever precedes const is const". `int const* i;` is much more concise than `const int *i;`.

Comment: The actual rule is that it is the same as declaring a variable, but putting `typedef` (almost) anywhere makes it declaring a type alias instead of a variable. People usually put it at the front for clarity

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It turns out that `typedef` can be placed after the existing type (in addition to before it). This little oddity, now obsolescent<sup>*</sup>, is caused by the way in which the C standard "bundles" `typedef`s with *storage class specifiers*, such as `static` and `auto`:

A *declaration* is defined as follows:

```
<declaration> ::=  {<declaration-specifier>}+ {<init-declarator>}*
```

This means that declaration specifiers can appear in any order. Now, *declaration specifier* is

```
<declaration-specifier> ::= <storage-class-specifier>
                          | <type-specifier>
                          | <type-qualifier>
```

And *storage class specifier* is

```
<storage-class-specifier> ::= auto
                        | register
                        | static
                        | extern
                        | typedef
```

The declaration of the `struct`'s elements is a type specifier. Like `typedef` keyword, it is a declaration specifier. Since declaration specifiers can appear in any order, both placements of `typedef` (i.e., before and after the `struct`) are valid and identical to each other.

<sup>*</sup> [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), 6.11.5: "The placement of a storage-class specifier other than at the beginning of the declaration specifiers in a declaration is an obsolescent feature." Thanks, [Keith Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/827263/keith-thompson), for a great comment!

Comment: [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)  6.11.5: "The placement of a storage-class specifier other than at the beginning of the declaration specifiers in a declaration is an obsolescent feature." It's still perfectly legal, but a future version of the language might make it illegal.